# Updating a list of embedded documents in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm struggling with mongoengine syntax.

I have the following models...

```
class Post(EmbeddedDocument):
    uid = StringField(required=True)
    text = StringField(required=True)
    when = DateTimeField(required=True)


class Feed(Document):
    label = StringField(required=True)
    feed_url = StringField(required=True)
    posts = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Post))

    def my_method(self, post):
        pass
```

... and with the post object passed into to my_method, I'd like to update an existing post if it exists in self.posts with a matching uid, or push to self.posts if not.

Is there syntax to do that in one call in mongoengine?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No with list field you cannot do an upsert into a list in a single query.  `$addToSet` wont work as you've changed the `post` so you cant match. You can code round this but it does create a race condition where there is a small window of opportunity for error eg:

```
    class Post(EmbeddedDocument):
        uid = StringField(required=True)
        text = StringField(required=True)

    class Feed(Document):
        label = StringField(required=True)
        feed_url = StringField(required=True)
        posts = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Post))

    Feed.drop_collection()

    Feed(
        label="label",
        feed_url="www.feed.com"
    ).save()

    post = Post(uid='1', text="hi")
    updated = Feed.objects(posts__uid=post.uid).update_one(set__posts__S=post)
    if not updated:
        Feed.objects.update_one(push__posts=post)
```

First we try to update and if it doesn't exist we push to the list - this is where there is a window of opportunity for another process to run and potentially push the `post` on the list.

The risk might be acceptable but realistically, I think changing your schema is better, potentially splitting `Post` out into its own collection.  Then you can use an update statement and set the whole object.  The cost will be an extra query to get the feed data.

Comment: @Ross how to get this response `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })` using `mongoengine`? I want to check whether the item was found. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Feed.objects.filter(posts__uid=post.uid).\
          update_one(push__posts__S__comments='comment demo')
```