# How to update embedded document inside embedded document and inside another embedded document using mongoengine

Tags: python, mongoengine

How do I update values of nested embedded documents using `mongoengine`, here is my schema:

```
class Stories(db.Document):
    id = db.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
    name = db.StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    story_knowledges = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField(StoryKnowledges))

class StoryKnowledges(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    id = db.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
    params = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField(Params))

class Params(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    id = db.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
    name = db.StringField(required=True)
```

How can I effectively update the Params document or update the `StoryKnowledges` document using `mongoengine`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a list of embedded documents in mongoengine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387478/updating-a-list-of-embedded-documents-in-mongoengine)